# Running 100,000 processes concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

I am simulating a banking system in which I have 100,000 transactions to run. Each type of transaction implements runnable, and I have various types of transactions which can occur.

`transactions` is an array of Runnables.

Ideally, the following code would solve my issue:

```
for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
    new Thread(transaction).start();
}
```

However, obviously a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` is bound to occur when attempting to start 100,000 threads.

So next I tried implementing an ExecutorService to create a thread pool to manage my 100,000 runnables.

```
ExecutorService service;
int cpus = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
// cpus == 8 in my case
service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpus);

for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
    service.execute(transaction);
}
```

When trying this approach, long processes "hog" the JVM. For example, one type of transaction takes 30 - 60 seconds to execute. When profiling the application, no other threads are being allowed to run while the long transaction takes place.

[image: In this case, thread 6 did not allow any other threads to run until its single transaction was complete]

In this case, thread 6 did not allow any other threads to run until its processing was complete.

So my question is: How can I run 100,000 transactions as fast as possible without running into memory problems? If ExecutorService is the answer, then how can I stop very long transactions from hogging the JVM and allow other transactions to run concurrently?

**EDIT:**

I am forcing certain types of transactions to occur for 30 - 60 seconds on purpose to ensure that my threaded program is working correctly. Each transaction locks on a single account, and there are 10 accounts. Here is my method which hogs the JVM: ( called by `run()` )

```
public void makeTransaction() {
    synchronized(account) {
        long timeStarted = System.nanoTime();
        long timeToEnd = timeStarted + nanos;

        this.view = new BatchView(transactionNumber, account.getId());

        this.displayView();

        while(true) {
            if(System.nanoTime() % 1000000000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("batch | " + account.getId());
            }

            if(System.nanoTime() >= timeToEnd) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time this transaction gets run, only the one account gets locked, leaving 9 others that should be available for processing. **How come the JVM does not process any more threads, and instead hangs until this long transaction finishes?**

Here is a link to a minified version of the project to demonstrate the problem: [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6iarxunlkk82mij/2eminified.zip?dl=0)

Comment: You should not create same amount of thread as transactions. Rather create specific fixed number of threads like 100 and let them do work on 100000 transactions using ExecutorsService

Comment: Can you show [a complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: Whats the name of the profiler you used?

Comment: @michael malura the default profiler built into Netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your application is that very soon all threads will have assigned a transaction for the same account, and then all but one thread have to wait. You can see this in the following screenshot, were I paused the application. Thread pool-1-thread-3 is currently handling a transaction for the Account object with id 19 (this id is not your account id, but a unique object id Eclipse assigns), and all other threads are waiting for the lock on the same Account object. The account object is the one where your id is 9.

[image: Screenshot of debugger]

Why does this happen? In transaction 853, one thread starts the first long running transaction (for account 9). The other threads continue to work on the other transactions. However, when any of the threads reaches another transaction for account 9, it will have to stop and wait. Transactions 857, 861, and 862 are also for account 9, and each blocks one thread, so at this time all my threads are blocked (on my quad core).

How to solve this? This depends on your use case.

If in your actual program it is guaranteed that there is no incoming transaction for a given account X as long as there is another transaction running for account X, you do not need to change anything.

If your number of accounts is very large compared to the number of threads, the problem becomes more unlikely, so you might decide to live with it.

If your number of accounts is relatively low (let's say maybe less than hundred or so), you should (as Peter said) have a single (endlessly-running) thread per account, each with its own transaction queue. This would probably be more efficient, because the threads do not need to "fight" over the shared queue.

Another solution would be to implement some form of "work stealing". This means that whenever a thread would be blocked, it instead looks for some other work to do. To implement this, you first need to be able to check whether a thread could get the lock for a given account. With `synchronized` in Java this is not possible, so you need something like [`ReentrantLock.tryLock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock()). You also need to be able to directly access the transaction queue from each thread, so I guess you cannot use `ExecutorService` here but need to implement transaction handling yourself (using a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)).

Now each thread would poll transactions from the queue in a loop. First it tries to acquire the lock for the respective account with `tryLock()`. If this fails, add the transaction to a (thread-specific) list, fetch the next transaction from the queue, and try for this one, until you find a transaction you can handle. After a transaction was finished, first look in the list for now-possible-to handle transactions before pulling another transaction from the global queue. The code could you roughly like the following:

```
public BlockingQueue<Transaction> queue = ...; // the global queue for all threads

public void run() {
   LinkedList<Transaction> myTransactions = new LinkedList<>();
   while (true) {
     Transaction t = queue.take();
     while (!t.getLock().tryLock()) {
        myTransactions.add(t);
     }
     try {
       // here we hold the lock for t
       t.makeTransaction();
     } finally {
       t.getLock().unlock();
     }

     Iterator<Transaction> iter = myTransactions.iterator();
     while (iter.hasNext()) {
       t = iter.next();
       if (t.getLock().tryLock()) {
         try {
           t.makeTransaction();
         } finally {
           t.getLock().unlock();
         }
         iter.remove();
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Note that this still has at least the following problems you might want to address:

- While a thread hangs in `queue.take()`, it does not check whether the transactions in its list have become available. So if there are periods of time where `queue` is empty (at the end of processing for example), there might be transactions stuck in the lists that are not being handled.
- If a significant amount of locks is being held by some of the threads, the remaining threads could take a lot of transactions that they cannot handle right now, so they would just fill their local list, draining the global queue. When the locks are released, many transactions might have been removed from the global queue, creating an imbalance between the work the threads can do (some threads might be idling while others are still working on their long backlog of transactions).

A simpler alternative might be to `put()` transactions into the queue (at the end) if you cannot acquire the lock for them, but this would make them executed in a very arbitrary order (which may happen with the above solution, too, but maybe not so extremely).

*Edit:*
A better solution might be to attach a queue to each account instead of thread-specific lists. Then a thread would add a transaction to the queue of the respective account whenever it finds this account blocked. When a thread finishes a transaction for account X, it should first look in the queue of account X, if any transactions have been added there, before looking at the global list.

Answer (score 10):

> When profiling the application, no other threads are being allowed to run while the long transaction takes place.

Most likely, this task is using a resource which is single threaded. i.e the way ti is written prevents concurrent usage.

> How can I run 100,000 transactions as fast as possible without running into memory problems?

If the transactions are CPU bound, you should have a pool about the same size as the number of CPUs you have.

If the transactions depend on a database, you should look at batching them to utilise the database more efficiently.

> If ExecutorService is the answer, then how can I stop very long transactions from hogging the JVM and allow other transactions to run concurrently?

Make the transactions much shorter.  If you have a task which runs for more than a few milli-seconds you should work out why is it taking so long.  I would start by looking at how must network/IO is it using and profiling the task.  Most transactions (if you have a large number) should be around 0.01 seconds or far less ideally.

You should take great care to consider how shared resources are used.  If your tasks use the same resources too much, you may find that multi-threading is no faster, or is even slower.

Comment: Each transaction locks on a single account (there are 10 accounts). The long transaction is on purpose: I lock on the single selected account for a random amount of time between 30 - 60 seconds to see how the system will react. When one account is locked for 30 seconds, the other accounts are still free to be mutated by the other threads in the pool. No database to worry about and I have a thread pool the same size as the number of CPUs that I have. What else am I missing?

Comment: @Feek most likely all the tasks are waiting on the same account.  You only need a very slightly unbalanced workload to get into this state.  If you only have 10 accounts, a much more sane approach is to have 10 threads where you assign all the work for each account to its own thread.  This way they will also run in parallel as the threads will never be attempting to access the same account.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to calculate the number of worker thread which can process transactions for you parallely based on your hardware. There are few formulas available to size the thread pool

For CPU Bound applications

> N * U or (N+1)*U

For IO bound applications

> N * U * (1+W/C)

where
**N** - Number of processors
**U** - target CPU Utilization
**W** - Wait time
**C** - Compute Time

For example if your application is utilizing 50% CPU and you have a 8 cores. Then for CPU bound applications to achieve efficient multithreading you have

> 8 * (0.5) = 4

If you have 4 threads then all your cores will be processing efficiently. This changes in some boars which support [hyperthreading](https://superuser.com/questions/329904/what-are-threads-and-what-do-they-do-in-the-processor)

Answer (score -1):

Performing 100,000 calls in separate threads is tough to do if you doing from a laptop or even 16-core desktop. You will need a grid or bunch of servers to optimally perform this.

However, you can still stretch this by doing whatever transaction operation in a `callback`. Your throughput can increase.